# Reverse each element in List[String] in Scala

Tags: list, scala, foreach

I'm still learning the basics and I have a question.

I have a function

```
def reverse(s: String): String = {
  s.reverse
}
```

Now I have a List[String] and I want to reverse each String element.
I've tried foreach, but it seems to return Unit, not String.
So, I want a List[String] with the same elements, but the strings reversed.

List(abcd, efgh) becomes List(dcba, hgfe).

What I have now:

```
def reverse(ls : List[String]):List[String] = {
  List(ls.foreach (reverse))
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Use map method:

```
List("abcd", "efgh").map(s => reverse(s))
```

Or simply:

```
List("abcd", "efgh").map(reverse)
```

Unlike foreach which is here for side effects (like printing things out) map *does* returns result.

Comment: Ahh, I missed the map method in the Scala API. Thanks!

Comment: Other useful methods you may want to look into (not for this problem, but for future use) are `filter`, `foldLeft/Right`, and `reduce`.

Comment: @adelbertc I would also add `.collect` to the list ;-)

Comment: And: `find`, `flatMap`, `groupBy`, `partition`, `exists` / `forall` and so on and so forth. It never hurts to just peruse the ScalaDoc. You can learn things... I discovered `corresponds` while making up the samples for this comment!

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
List("abcd", "efgh").reverse
```